# Java summation of 2 list and stored in a list

Tags: java

```
public static list Sum2List(list L1, list L2) {
    list l = new list();
    l.first = new listNode(0, null);
    listNode x = l.first;
    for (listNode p = L1.first, p1 = L2.first; (p != null && p1 != null); p = p.next, p1 = p1.next) {
        x.data = p.data + p1.data;
        x.next = new listNode(0, null);
    }
    return l;
}

it shows some error and i think their is error in my coding too.plz if anyone can help out.guys in output its jst showing two values
```

is it possible to write these codes of method to sum list using while loop??

Comment: Also, have you thought of actually referencing the list correctly? You're literally setting the list's value every time you do the addition. Do you want to simply add two generic lists? Or custom lists?

Comment: it says that int cannot be converted to list.

Comment: What type is `list`? what types are `p.data` and `p1.data`?  I would wager you are either trying to add things that can't be added, or assign something that can to the wrong type.

Comment: Yup. That's what I pointed to, the fact that you aren't referencing any value for the list.

Comment: Is ´list´ your own class without a capital L, does that even compile? If you are trying to use java List then you need to use capital L.

Comment: You'll need to create a new `listNode` for each sum and append it to `l`. Do you really intend to sum every element of `L1` with every element of `L2`?

Comment: this is provided from bfr n based on this im writing the code
    public static class listNode {

        int data;
        listNode next;

        listNode(int d, listNode n) {
            data = d;
            next = n;
        }
    }

    public static class list {

        listNode first;
    }

Comment: @user3574078: I edited the question to add the code from your comment.

Comment: @Fred Larson can we do it usin a while loop

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code, made to work. This isn't normally how you would do it in java, this looks more like a scripting language like perl.

```
public class SomeLists {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list l1 = new list();
        l1.first = new listNode();
        l1.first.data = 1;
        l1.first.next = new listNode();
        l1.first.next.data = 2;

        list l2 = new list();
        l2.first = new listNode();
        l2.first.data = 3;
        l2.first.next = new listNode();
        l2.first.next.data = 4;

        list sum = SomeLists.Sum2List(l1, l2);
        assert (sum.first.data == 3);
        assert (sum.first.next.data == 6);
    }

    public static list Sum2List(list L1, list L2) {
        list l = new list();
        listNode currentNode = null;
        for (listNode p1 = L1.first; p1 != null; p1 = p1.next) {
            for (listNode p2 = L2.first; p2 != null; p2 = p2.next) {
                listNode newNode = new listNode();
                newNode.data = p1.data + p2.data;

                if (currentNode == null) {
                    // first time only
                    l.first = newNode;
                }
                else {
                    // all other times
                    currentNode.next = newNode;
                }
                // move currentNode forward.
                currentNode = newNode;
            }
        }
        return l;
    }

    private static class list {
        public listNode first;
    }

    private static class listNode {
        public listNode next;
        public int data;
    }
}
```

If you want to have it more like Java then it should be object oriented, member variables should be private and accessed through getters and setters. Something like this.

```
public class SomeLists {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyList l1 = new MyList();
        ListNode listNode1 = new ListNode(1);
        l1.add(listNode1);
        ListNode listNode2 = new ListNode(2);
        l1.add(listNode2);

        MyList l2 = new MyList();
        ListNode listNode3 = new ListNode(3);
        l2.add(listNode3);
        ListNode listNode4 = new ListNode(4);
        l2.add(listNode4);

        MyList sum = SomeLists.Sum2List(l1, l2);
        ListNode first = sum.getFirst();
        ListNode second = first.getNext();
        assert (first.getData() == 3);
        assert (second.getData() == 6);
    }

    public static MyList Sum2List(MyList L1, MyList L2) {
        MyList sum = new MyList();

        ListNode currentNode1 = L1.getFirst();
        ListNode currentNode2 = L2.getFirst();
        while (currentNode1 != null && currentNode2 != null) {
            sum.add(new ListNode(currentNode1.getData() + currentNode2.getData()));
            currentNode1 = currentNode1.getNext();
            currentNode2 = currentNode2.getNext();
        }

        return sum;
    }

    private static class MyList {
        private ListNode first;

        public void add(ListNode listNode) {
            if (first == null) {
                this.first = listNode;
            }
            else {
                first.addLast(listNode);
            }
        }

        public ListNode getFirst() {
            return first;
        }
    }

    private static class ListNode {
        private ListNode next;
        private int data;

        public ListNode(int i) {
            this.data = i;
        }

        public void addLast(ListNode listNode) {
            if (this.next == null) {
                this.next = listNode;
            }
            else {
                this.next.addLast(listNode);
            }
        }

        public ListNode getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public int getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Then again, why implement the wheel? There is already a list in Java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SomeLists {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        l1.add(1);
        l1.add(2);

        l2.add(3);
        l2.add(4);

        List<Integer> sum = SomeLists.Sum2List(l1, l2);
        assert (sum.get(0) == 3);
        assert (sum.get(1) == 6);
    }

    public static List<Integer> Sum2List(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) {
        List<Integer> sum = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < l1.size() && i < l2.size(); i++) {
            sum.add(l1.get(i) + l2.get(i));
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this. Not the best. But a way :

```
public static list Sum2List(list L1, list L2) {
    list l=null;
    int listCounter = 0;
    for (listNode p = L1.first; p != null; p = p.next) {
        for (listNode p1 = L2.first; p1 != null; p1 = p1.next) {
            l.set(listCounter++, p.data + p1.data);
        }
    }
    return l;
}
```

In the methods list, make a method add. Say if your underlying data structure was an ArrayList, then you would do :

```
public void set(int index, int value) {
    this.arrayList.set(index,value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this is the solution for problem

  public static list Sum2List(list L1, list L2) {
        list l = new list();
        l.first = new listNode(0, null);
        listNode x = l.first;
        for (listNode p = L1.first, p1 = L2.first; (p != null && p1 != null); p = p.next, p1 = p1.next) {
            if (p.next != null && p1.next != null) {
                x.next = new listNode(p.data + p1.data, x.next);
            } else {
                x.data = p.data + p1.data;
            }
        }
        return l;
    }
```